# unable to get the MMult property of the WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba

everyone, I got a strange problem, please help.

**the error message is:**

> Run-time error '1004'
>
> Unable to get the `MMult` property of the `WorksheetFunction` class

1, I use a program name is "`schedule`" to automaticly run my VBA program everyday, but the VBA program will fail everyday, but when I control my "schedule program" to automatically run it again to try to reproduce this error, I can't get it, it run smooth.

2, When this error occured, Excel will show **[end] [debug]** window, I click **[debug]** and press **[F5]**, it run smooth; it supposes show error again if parameters for MMult are incorrect.

3, I have written a sub to dump my data which use in `mmult`, it are same in error occur and no error.

so, I can assume the two parameters for `mmult` are correct, but why I got the error message everyday?

**this most hard thing is it is hard to reproduce this error.**

**code:**

```
Public Function Regression(ByVal X As Variant, ByVal y As Variant)
    writelog ("Regression")
    writelog ("dump x")
    Call dumpRange(X, 2)
    writelog ("dump y")
    Call dumpRange(y, 1)
    
    Dim xtrans, temp, temp2, b
    xtrans = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(X)
    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(xtrans, X)     ' occour error on this line
    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(temp)
    temp2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(xtrans, y)
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(temp, temp2)
    Regression = b
End Function
```

X is a Range like this

```
1  0.34343323
1  1.32323323
1  1.21111221
1  0.33444232
.  ......
```

Window 7 home preminum 64bit

office 2010 professional 64bit / 32bit sp1

Comment: Can you paste the line of code that the debugger highlights

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. What is the exact error (number and message)?

Comment: After you click debug it should highlight the line where the issue is in yellow

Comment: debugger highlights line: temp = Application.WorkSheetFunction.MMult(xtrans, X)

Comment: Please show us your full code so that we can understand what is each var. You can edit your question by clicking on the `edit` button at the bottom left of your question

Comment: If it runs OK when stepping though the code in the Debug session, it's possible you have some kind of race/timing issue.  Try adding a `DoEvents` call just before the problem line.

Comment: That's a good suggest, I will try it see if it work.

Comment: I have reinstalled my OS and office, it work fine now. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled my OS and office, it work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I think this is where you are getting your error

```
temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(xtrans,
Application.Transpose(X))
```

Comment: I did Transpose() before I do MMult. and as I said, the error not occur everytime, when I try to run it again with same data, it is no problem there.

Comment: I would eliminate that line or comment out those lines and replace both with this it should work ok

Comment: As I said, the error not occur everytime, when I try to run it again with exactly same data, it is no problem there.

Comment: They are having the exact same error that you are having and they used this method as well. http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/537441-solved-mmult-and-minv.html Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: thank you very much, I have searched this problem on google, and I had saw this url before I post here.

Comment: I have reinstalled my OS and office, it work fine now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But it turned out mine was caused by a dimension problem.

I did:

```
Redim Y(obs)
Redim X(obs,3)
Xtransposed = Application.worksheetfunction.transpose(X)
MMult = Application.worksheetfunction.mmult(Xtransposed, Y)
```

While I should have done Redim Y(obs,1) to make the code work.

So:

```
Redim Y(obs,1)
Redim X(obs,3)
Xtransposed = Application.worksheetfunction.transpose(X)
MMult = Application.worksheetfunction.mmult(Xtransposed, Y)
```